# Powershell script to recursively capture all ADGroups and Members

Tags: powershell

We are trying to do a massive overhaul of security groups so I am looking to put together a script that will export out all AD groups with members including nested groups.  Such that when exported to excel it will be in a

```
Top Level Group - Member
                - Nested group (if any)
                                        - Member
                                        - Nested group (if any)

etc....
```

I've seen that nested groups and recursion like this is pretty tricky, and in looking for examples I haven't come across anything that seems to fit this, anyone have examples of something like this?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please note that [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com) is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I used this script (https://github.com/andyzib/Scripts/blob/master/PowerShell/AD_Nested_Groups/Get-ADNestedGroupMembers.ps1) and it worked really well. He has written it in a function and you can get info using the following commands:

```
.EXAMPLE   
Get-ADNestedGroupMembers "MyGroup" | Export-CSV .\NedstedMembers.csv -NoTypeInformation

.EXAMPLE  
Get-ADGroup "MyGroup" | Get-ADNestedGroupMembers | ft -autosize
            
.EXAMPLE             
Get-ADNestedGroupMembers "MyGroup" -indent
```